# Can someone correct my code over here? Also, can someone tell me the proper way to define a function in Java?

Tags: java

This code does not run when I try to compile it, I am sure it is because I 
  defined my function/method incorrectly, so it would be much appreciated if 
  someone can  correct my code and also tell me what is wrong with it.

I know C++ so I tried to define the function like how I would define it 
  normally in Cpp but with a few tweaks. I really don't know what I am doing 
  right now.

```
 class Calculator {
     public static void main(String[] arguments) {

         float Celcius;
         float Farenheit = 32;
         final float k = 5 / 9;
         System.out.println("This is the temperature in degrees celsius: " +
             Converter(Farenheit));

         public float Converter(float Farenheit) {
             return 5 / 9 * (Farenheit - 32);
         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: If you write `5.0 / 9`, rather than `5 / 9`, you avoid that pesky integer division truncation.  Or writing `(Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9` will work too.

Comment: Why not start by learning Java from scratch? There are various good and comprehensive online resources for that. Also learn to use IDE and read the error/warning message displayed regarding syntax error

Comment: `public float Converter(float Farenheit)` is defined inside main, you **can nott** define methods within methods

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Opps, corrected ;)

Answer (score 1):

So the comments noted the key issues. The method cannot be within main. 5/9=0 in Java. Here is a little program I just checked on jdoodle.com. It does what you said in what might be typical Java style (though for sure there are possible improvements and things with which to quibble). For learning Java (which is not the same as for experienced users for development), bluej is an interesting IDE with which to start (specifically because it doesn't do all the work for you). But StackOverflow does not want judgment questions like that, so ignore if you wish.

```
public class Calculator {
    public double converter(double Farenheit) {// convention converter lower case because not a class name
         return 5.0 / 9 * (Farenheit - 32); //note 5.0 ensures real number arithmetic, not integer
     }

 public static void main(String[] arguments) {
     Calculator calculator = new Calculator();// make a calculator object, alternative would be to declare converter static 
     double Farenheit = 32;
     System.out.println("This is the temperature in degrees celsius: " +
         calculator.converter(Farenheit));


 }


}
```

Comment: arguably farenheit should start with a lower case f. I tested with -40 and 212 as well, to show it did not return 0 for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your method public float Converter(float Farenheit) is written inside main method . This is not allowed in JAVA . You can however write a anonymous class inside a method and calls its methods .

The correct code is :

```
  class Calculator {
 private static final float k = 5.0f / 9;
 public static void main(String[] arguments) {

     float Celcius;
     float Farenheit = 32;

     System.out.println("This is the temperature in degrees celsius: " +
     Converter(Farenheit));
 }

 public static float Converter(float Farenheit) {
         return k * (Farenheit - 32);
     }
```

}

Please note I have modified Converter method to a static one . We cannot call non static methods from static context in JAVA(as main is static here) . If Converter would have been non static then we would have to create an object of the Calculator class.

```
Calculator c = new Calculator();
c.Converter(Fahrenheit);
```

You can declare k as class level variable if it is to be used across multiple methods and has a constant value .

> private static final float k = 5.0f / 9;